# Get mySql queries displaying using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a student table in my database which I am trying to display all the records in. I followed a tutorial on how to query however its not working with what I've got so far. Solutions to this appreciated.
My code:

```
  ?php
                $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'sportsday') or die("Unable to connect");

                    //echo "Connected";
                    error_reporting(0);


                    if ($result = $db->query("SELECT  * FROM student")) {

                        if ($result->num_rows) {


                            $count= $result->num_rows;

                                if ($count > 0) {
                                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()); {

                                    echo $row['surname'], " ", $row['forename'];
                                    }
                                    //$result-> free();

                                }

                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Any errors received?  You have a lot of extra num_rows code you don't need, but other than that, it "should" run.

Comment: the browser produces a blank page, so no errors. its not outputting the results from the query. I did follow a tutorial so if extra lines are there then tell me which ones are not needed, thanks

Comment: remove ` error_reporting(0);` to see the errors, or set it to `E_ALL`

Comment: @OlegDubas set it to e_all , thanks. I am getting a undefined index for 'surname' and 'forename' now

Answer (score 1):

First of all in your development environment turn your errors on and tune up your error reporting either through php.ini or programtically like:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

That will let you see the errors you are making and alert you to issues. Now having said that the tow things that immediately stand out are syntax errors...

1. a dot (`.`) is the string concatenation operator not a comma (`,`) so
   `echo $row['surname'], " ", $row['forename'];`

   Should be:

   `echo $row['surname'] . " " . $row['forename'];`
2. You have a errant semicolon in your `while` loop...

   `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()); {`

   should be:

   `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {`

So putting it all together:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'sportsday') or die("Unable to connect");

if ($result = $db->query("SELECT  * FROM student")) {

    if ($result->num_rows) {

        $count = $result->num_rows;

            if ($count > 0) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                    echo $row['surname'] . " " . $row['forename'];
                }
                //$result-> free();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks, just corrected these problems. how would i fix a undefined index ('surname' and 'forename') are saying this in the browser.

Comment: commented the echo line and tested 'print_r($row);' instead, it showed all the records in the array when I tried this. its just the problem with an 'undefined index'